# lmer: "Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations"

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I am trying to run a linear mixed model for a sentiment analysis with movie reviews. There are 32000 different `title`s in my data frame and each title has a varying number of reviews (`review_number`). `review_number` is a sequence starting from 1 for each title and is 937 at max. I calculated the emotionality and extremity for each review. The dummy `critic` indicates whether a review was written by a critic. I want to nest the reviews within titles. In total there are 1.2 Mio observations.

Sample:

```
      title critic review_number  review_emo review_extr
1 '64 - '95      0             1 -0.75908061   0.1051023
2 '64 - '95      0             2 -1.78770128  -1.2697559
3 '64 - '95      0             3  0.04826126   1.1797093
4 '64 - '95      0             4  1.56405819   0.5269304
5 '64 - '95      0             5 -0.82757559   0.1753819
6 '64 - '95      0             6  0.68578835  -0.5778072
```

This is the model I used:

```r
mod <- lmer(review_emo ~ critic + review_extr + (1 | title/review_number),
              data = df)
```

I receive this error message:

> Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations (problems: review_number:title)

Why is that and how can I fix it? My grouping factor should be smaller than the number of observations because there are 32000 titles and a maximum of 937 reviews per title. I checked the number of levels with `nlevels(x)`.

I looked this problem up in various posts but I can`t tell why it does not work for me.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. What is the reason that you use `title/review_number` as your grouping factor? I would suggest to only use `title` as your grouping factor.

Comment: Hello Noah, it is a replication study and I try to follow the analysis steps of the original study as close as possible. In the original study the reviews were nested within the movies (`title`s).

Comment: This error results from the way the model is specified, and is therefore more of a stats question than a programming question. I am recommending that the question be moved to Cross Validated.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have only one observation per combination of title and review number; this means that the nested "review number within title" variance term is completely confounded with the residual variance.

To expand on that a little bit: `(1|title/review_number)` expands to `(1|title) + (1|title:review_number)`, where the grouping variable for the second term is the *interaction* between title and review number.

It's hard to see how this approach would ever have worked (it would only work if there were more than observation per title/review number combination, which seems unlikely given the way the data are described).

- You could simply drop the `review_number` term: you won't be missing anything, as this level of variation is already captured in the residual variation
- you can override this check if you want (see `?lme4::lmerControl`, specifically the `check.nobs.vs.nlev` setting). If you do, then the residual variance will be **arbitrarily** divided between residual variance and review-within-title variance (as any linear combination that adds up to the total variance at the observation level will have the same log-likelihood).
- if you use the `glmmTMB` package you could force the residual variance to zero (or very small, to be precise: `dispformula ~ 0`), so that all of the observation-level variance would be assigned to the review-within-trial term. (This still won't change the log-likelihood.)