# lmer: "Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations

Tags: r, nested, lme4

I am using the following model:

```r
fit_nested <- lmer(value.my ~ value.open + age.true + (1|year/curveID), 
                   data = test, REML = FALSE)
```

I am receiving this error in R:

> number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations (problems: curveID:year, year)

The data frame:
[image: the data frame]

I am unsure what is going wrong. I converted the variables to factors which I understood is needed but the error remains. I cant tell why the model is not running.

Comment: (ps please dont add images of code : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Is that literally your whole data frame? Because you have 7 observations and 7 different values for year (and 7 levels of `test$curveID:test$year`), so the error is simply pointing out that fact. If you just duplicate the last row (`test <- rbind(test, test[7,])`), it runs fine whether or not you convert the variables to factors. I don't know whether your approach makes sense from a modeling standpoint, but just in R code terms, that's why you're getting the error.

Comment: (1) You probably have a single observation per year/curveID combination, which means that the year-by-curveID random effect is confounded with the residual variance term. (2) Have you looked at [the other questions on SO that refer to this error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+Error%3A+number+of+levels+of+each+grouping+factor+must+be+%3C+number+of+observations)? Do they answer your question? If not, can you explain why not? (Can you explain why converting the variables to factors would help/give a link to where that solution is discussed?)

Comment: Hi thank you for the comments! I checked the post 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73661193/lmer-error-number-of-levels-of-each-grouping-factor-must-be-number-of-obser' already before posting this question but I now understand that I have the same situation.  Then my roblem is solved and I will continue with this model instead: fit_year <- lmer (value.my ~ value.open + age.true + (1|curveID)+ (1|year),  data = data.ready, REML = F)
The image I shared is only the top part of my data frame which has 490 rows. Sorry for the confusion.